# Why does Haskell consider lambda abstractions to be in Weak Head Normal Form (WHNF)?

Tags: haskell, weak-head-normal-form

In Haskell, lambdas are considered to be in WHNF, while unapplied user-defined functions are not. What was the motivation behind this distinction?

Comment: Note that as was somewhat discussed in that linked possible duplicate, the distinction between what is considered WHNF and what is considered something that will certainly, in a short time and without side effects evaluate *into* WHNF is a somewhat arbitrary decision.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's often useful to attach information to a function that needs to be calculated before you can ever evaluate the function, but that can afterwards be shared across invocations.

```
cleverFunction = \x -> simpleCombine x expensiveConstant
 where expensiveConstant = ...
       simpleCombine x c = ...
```

Note that though `cleverFunction` is defined as a lambda, it is not in WHNF because of the `where` block (sugar for `(\l x -> ...) locBindings`).

A lambda without any enclosing scope has no variables that could be calculated before invocation (variables *in* the lambda are only valid for a single call, and garbage-collected afterwards), i.e. it is already in normal form (actually NF, not just WHNF).

Comment: Even `\x -> (1 + 1 :: Integer)`?

Comment: It seems like `(1 + 1 :: Integer)` could be reduced to `2 :: Integer` before the lambda is called

Comment: Well, yes, but that would be a matter of optimisation. Most definitely, `\x -> 1 + undefined` does not try to evaluate the result unless you call the function. I.e. _semantically_, a lambda is always already in NF.